# How do I import a census table into SAS when the variable name has special characters in it?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide, importing American Community Survey tables from the census into a script to work with them. Here is an example of a raw census csv I'm importing into SAS Enterprise Guide:

[image]

within my data step, when I use the command

```
County=Geo.display-label;
```

I get this error:

[image]

In base SAS, I was using

```
County=Geo_display_label;
```

While that worked in base SAS, when I tried that in Enterprise Guide, I got this error:
[image]

What is a way to get the raw data's variable name Geo.display-label to read into SAS Enterprise Guide correctly?

Comment: Run PROC CONTENTS on the dataset generated by your IMPORT method of choice. Then use the name that got assigned. If the name does not meet normal SAS naming conventions then you will need to use a name literal like `'Geo.display-label'n`.  IT doesn't hurt anything to use a name literal for a name that doesn't require it, like `'name'n`.

Answer (score 2):

To see the impact of the VALIDVARNAME option on the names that PROC IMPORT generates when the column headers are not valid SAS names lets make a little test CSV file.

```
filename csv temp ;

data _null_;
 file csv ;
 put 'GEO.id,GEO.id2,GEO.display-label';
 put 'id1,id2,geography';
run;
```

If we run PROC IMPORT to convert that into a SAS datasets when VALIDVARNAME option is set to ANY then it will use the column headers exactly, including the illegal characters like period and hyphen. To reference the variables with those illegal characters we will need to use name literals.

```
options validvarname=any;
proc import datafile=csv replace out=test1 dbms=dlm;
  delimiter=',';
run;
proc contents data=test1; run;
proc freq data=test1;
  tables 'GEO.display-label'n ;
run;
```

But if we set the option to V7 instead then it will convert the illegal characters into underscores.

```
options validvarname=v7;
proc import datafile=csv replace out=test2 dbms=dlm;
  delimiter=',';
run;

proc contents data=test2; run;
proc freq data=test2;
  tables geo_display_label ;
run;
```

Comment: So, it seems to have worked, but I'm still getting an "Error: Import Unsuccessful. See SAS Log for details." But the results tab shows my proc contents, data step, proc print and the results look right. Why is it still throwing me an error? Thank you for your help so far, by the way. I feel I'm 95% of the way there, but this is a big work project so I don't want to have errors.

Comment: Are you using an import task in EG or just a pure code task?  If  the SAS server see the file directly without having to have EG upload the file then just use the SAS code step.

Answer (score 1):

```
County = 'geo.display-label'n;
```

if you set OPTIONS VALIDVARNAME=V7; in EG you will get the same names as batch sas.

Comment: It didn't work, I got the "Error: The name GEO.display-label is not a valid SAS name." This code is in the data step. Before the data step I have a proc import statement where I'm bringing in the csv. Am I putting the options validvarname=V7 in the data step right before I define the County variable? That's what I was doing.

Comment: You need to change the validvarname option before the proc import for it to change how proc import creates the variable names.